# How to configure NestJS app for both Kafka and Postgres CRUD (Microservice) same time

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, nestjs

I'm implementing a Microservice application that uses 3 Spring boot Microservices and 1 NestJS Microsrvice. I was able to pass data using Kafka between Spring boot services as well as Spring boot to NestJS. I'm completely new to NestJS. I have used this code (main.ts) to configure NestJS Kafka consumer (Producer is Spring boot MS)

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
      },
      consumer: {
          groupId: 'groupId',
      }
    }
  });

  app.listen()
}
bootstrap();
```

I can get the Spring MS data to Nest app without issue. But, here There is no port number specifying to run the application. So, Can someone give me an idea about how to configure this one to further implement REST services using Postgres. (How to create endpoints and call them). Here if I call an endpoint using default port 3000, It will not work because of this Kafka configuration.

Comment: The Kafka transport doesn't prevent Nest's default Express server from running. But also, why do you need a web server with Nest? You can just use KafkaJS directly as a consumer... Otherwise, you haven't shown your consumer code, but you would put your Postgres commands in the consumer function, not the bootstrap function

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have a similar issue. I have a rest microservice that is written in nest. This microservice also needs to listen to a Kafka topic. Can this be accomplished?  , I have to do a lot of changes in main.ts it seems. I have to replace the nestfactory.create with nestfactory.createmicoservice.

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige As mentioned, there's nothing preventing nest server from using a Kafka consumer. Please create a new port and share your code